# Can arduino constantly check values while running a different function?

Tags: arduino, constants, sensors

I have an arduino R3 hooked up to a moisture sensor and a humidity/temperature sensor. Is there a way to use

```
millis();
```

instead of using

```
delay();
```

in a way that the rest of the program will run while in another function?

Basically my program checks the temperature, humidity, and soil moisture levels every few seconds. But say the moisture reading drops below 200, then a valve will turn on letting the plants get watered. If I wanted the valve to stay on for 5 minutes is there a way to do that while the temperature and humidity are being checked simultaneously? From what I have now its waits 5 minutes and finishes watering before it goes back to checking values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use millis().

For example, define how long you want the valve to stay opened, and declare another two variables to store if the valve has been opened, and when

```
long valveOpenedDuration = 60000;   // 60000 milliseconds => one minute
long timeWhenValveWasOpened;
bool valveIsOpened = false;
```

When you want to open the valve, just store when it's happening, and store that the valve is opened:

```
   timeWhenValveWasOpened = millis ();
   valveIsOpened = true;
```

and then in your loop you can call this function

```
void checkValve {
     if (valveIsOpened) {
         if (millis () - timeWhenValveWasOpened > valveOpenedDuration) {
               // do something here
               valveIsOpened = false;
         }
     }
}
```